# Tab Validation not happening for Dropdownlist only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, html.dropdownlistfor

I have written some validations for my fields to happen on tab out.The validations work for all the input fields but the dropdown fields dont get valdated.

My HTML is as shown

```
<head>
  <title>CREATE PROVIDER</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">    
    <h1 class="col-sm-offset-2">Enter Provider Details:</h1><br />
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="ProviderDetailsForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">FIRST NAME:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter the First Name" id="FirstName" data-bind="value: FirstName" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event);">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_FirstName">Enter the first name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">LAST NAME:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Last Name" id="LastName" data-bind="value: LastName" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event);">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_LastName">Enter the last name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">CERTIFICATION:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="Certification" data-bind="value:SelectedCertification,options: Certification, optionsCaption: 'Select a Certification'">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">SPECIALIZATION:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="Specialization" data-bind="value: Specialization">
                    <option>Select a Specialization</option>   
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">EMAIL ADDRESS:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: ContactEmail" placeholder="Enter your email address" id="EmailAddress">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_EmailAddress">Enter the Email Address</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="Submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-4">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/Create_Script.js"></script>
```

The JS script is

```
  $("#FirstName").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('borderclass');
        $("#Err_FirstName").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#Err_FirstName").hide();
        $(this).removeClass('borderclass');
    }
});

 //Scripts for the Certification
$("#Certification option:selected").blur(function () {
    if ($('#Certification :selected').text() == "Select a Certification")
        alert("Please choose a Certification");
});

//Scripts for the Specialization
$("#Specialization option:selected").blur(function () {
    if ($('#Specialization :selected').text() == "Select a Specialization")
        alert("Please choose a Specialization");
});
```

I have also attached an image
[image]

Could you please guide me in the right direction.Thanks.
I have also included the following jquery files in my solution if that helps
jquery.2.1.3.min.js and jquery-ui-1.11.2.js

Comment: For dropdownlists , remove `option:selected` in JS code and try.

Comment: I have tried that before.It does not work even without  'option:selected' keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/4vsr04o9/

```
$("#Specialization").blur(function () {
//alert("hello");
if ($('#Specialization :selected').text() == "Select a Specialization")
     alert("Select a Specialization");
});

<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">SPECIALIZATION:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="Specialization" data-bind="value: Specialization">
                    <option>Select a Specialization</option>   
                    <option>Hello World</option>   
                </select>
            </div>
</div>
```